# Pear SoapClient and Webservice Issue

Tags: web-services, soap, pear

I am trying to do a simple soap call to a weather service and I keep getting Invalid ZIP error. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong below is my code.

Thanks

```
require_once 'SOAP/Client.php'; 

$client = new Soap_Client('http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?WSDL'); 
$method = 'GetCityWeatherByZIP'; 
$params = array('ZIP' => '07108');   
$result = $client->call($method, $params); 

if (PEAR::isError($result)) { 
echo $result->getMessage(); 
} else { 
print_r($result); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's in-built SOAP client. The one in PEAR was written at a time PHP did not have one itself.

---

Their service is no SOAP service. The [wiki states](http://wiki.cdyne.com/index.php/CDYNE_Weather):

```
$url = "http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx/GetCityForecastByZIP";
$url .= "?ZIP=" . $this->ZipCode;
$this->response = simplexml_load_file($url) or die("ERROR");
```

Comment: Unfortunately my client hosting company does not support the built-in PHP SoapClient.